# How to use %in% (R) in scilab

Tags: r, scilab

Input can be an idframe object can be in matrix or dataframe form or it can just be numeric, I want to covert the code to scilab. I am stuck in how to use %in% in scilab.

```
if(class(input)=="idframe"){
    uk <- input$input[,1,drop=T]
  } else if(class(input) %in% c("matrix","data.frame")){
    uk <- input[,1,drop=T]
   } else if(is.numeric(input)){
    uk <- input
```

Comment: you could try a switch statement to cover the possible classes.

Answer (score 0):

Well... there's only two possibilities, so switch:

`else if(class(input) %in% c("matrix","data.frame")){`

for

`else if(class(input) == "matrix"|class(input) == "data.frame"){`

where `|` is a logical or.